# No se me actualiza el valor del <p:rating id="total" />

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estoy tratando de coger el valor de un rating y mostrarlo en otro rating:

```
<h:form id="frmVerCalificacionDetalle">
        <div id="VerCalificacionDetalle" class="cssBarra ui-dialog" style="display: none;  max-width: 400px !important;">
            <div class="cssBarra1"></div>
            <div class="cssBarra2"></div>
            <div class="cssClose" onclick="PF('wdgVerCalificacionDetalle').hide()">X</div>
        </div>
        <p:dialog id="dlgVerCalificacionDetalle"  widgetVar="wdgVerCalificacionDetalle" onShow="mostrar('VerCalificacionDetalle'); calculaIndexZ( 'frmVerCalificacionDetalle:dlgVerCalificacionDetalle','VerCalificacionDetalle');" onHide="ocultar('VerCalificacionDetalle');" modal="true" closable="fale" resizable="false" styleClass="cssDialogFrontend" style=" text-align:center; max-width: 400px !important; width: 80% !important">
            <p:rating id="total"  stars="5" cancel="false"  value="#{calificacionControlador.total}">

            </p:rating>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputLabel id="lblProveedorNombreCalificacionDetalle" value=""/>
            </f:facet>
            <p:dataScroller styleClass="cssPanelCalificacionDetalle"  rowIndexVar="rowCalificacionDetalle" id="dataCalificacion" var="listaCalificacionDetalle" scrollHeight="300" value="#{calificacionControlador.nuevo.calificaciondetalleCollection}" chunkSize="4" mode="inline" >
                <div id="divRate" style="width: 218px; height: 42px; position: relative;" align="center">
                    <p:rating id="rate"  stars="5" cancel="false" value="#{listaCalificacionDetalle.caldetvalor}" onRate=";alert(value);PF('total').update();">
                        <p:ajax  event="rate" listener="#{calificacionControlador.setTotal(listaCalificacionDetalle.caldetvalor)}"   />
                    </p:rating>
                </div>
            </p:dataScroller>
            <p:inputTextarea id="txtOpinion" placeholder="Ingrese un Mensaje" style="min-height: 150px" value="#{calificacionControlador.nuevo.calcomentario}" />
            <p:commandButton style="float: left"  actionListener="#{calificacionControlador.crear()}" update=":growlMensaje"/>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es actualizar el rating con id "total" al modificar el rating con id "rate", añade update="total" en el p:ajax del segundo p:rating.

Answer (score 0):

El el **p:ajax** debes agregar el update del **p:rating id="total"**  ejemplo:

```
<p:rating id="rate"  stars="5" cancel="false" value="#{listaCalificacionDetalle.caldetvalor}" onRate=";alert(value);PF('total').update();">
                        <p:ajax  event="rate" update="total" listener="#{calificacionControlador.setTotal(listaCalificacionDetalle.caldetvalor)}"   />
                    </p:rating>
```